# Developing staking coin

Tags: solidity, contract-development, staking, altcoin

I want to make a coin which can stake on Ethereum most of the functionality is done but I want to see some reference to see that if I'm missing anything. I can't find anything direct on google. Can anyone help me find any coin which can stake and has code for reference.
Thank you!!

Comment: Hi there. You mean a _token_ running on Ethereum? What do you mean by "stake"? What do people get when they stake the token? What are the slashing conditions?

Comment: It's like FD in normal banks when people put coins in staking for particular time period it will give return some percent of coin.